# Python Casting and parse the value of a variable

Tags: python

i have a name of a list in one variable let's say list_name = 'listA'
how can i loop in this list, like a casting .

e.g

```
list_name = 'listA'

for item in listA:
    print item

can you type something like for item in (list_name) or &list_name?
```

Thanxs

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>> listA = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> list_name = 'listA'
>>> for item in globals()[list_name]:
        print(item)
foo
bar
```